# Cannot save dropout layer in a tensorflow model with tf2onnx.convert.from_keras (and load it with onnx)

Tags: tensorflow, onnx, dropout, tf2onnx

Describe the bug

I want to save a model that I trained with tensorflow and that contains Dropout layers. I need these layers at inference to use them in training_mode in order to measure the epistemic uncertainty of my model. I think the tf2onnx convert.from_keras function does not save the dropout layer.

System information

```
Windows 11
Tensorflow Version: 2.7.0
Python version: 3.8.10
```

To Reproduce
Here is the code example that I use:

```
      import tf2onnx
      import onnx
      from tensorflow.keras.layers import ( Dense, Input, Dropout,)
      from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
      
      input_layer = Input(shape=(96))
      h = Dense(128, activation="relu")(input_layer)
      h = Dropout(0.1)(h)
      h = Dense(128, activation="relu")(h)
      h = Dropout(0.1)(h)
      h = Dense(12, activation=None)(h)
      
      model = Model(input_layer, h, name=name)
      
      model_onnx, _ =tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(model, output_path='test_dropout.onnx')
      
      test = onnx.load('test_dropout.onnx')
      test.graph.node
```

In the node displayed I have no mention of dropout. The thing is, I want to use the dropout layer in training_mode during inference to use MC dropout to have a measurement of the epistemic uncertainty.

Is there something I am doing wrong here ? Or is it just no possible to do so ?

The output of the `test.graph.node` is:

```
[input: "input_1"
input: "model/dense/MatMul/ReadVariableOp:0"
output: "model/dense/MatMul:0"
name: "model/dense/MatMul"
op_type: "MatMul"
, input: "model/dense/MatMul:0"
output: "model/dense/Relu:0"
name: "model/dense/Relu"
op_type: "Relu"
, input: "model/dense/Relu:0"
input: "model/dense_1/MatMul/ReadVariableOp:0"
output: "model/dense_1/MatMul:0"
name: "model/dense_1/MatMul"
op_type: "MatMul"
, input: "model/dense_1/MatMul:0"
output: "model/dense_1/Relu:0"
name: "model/dense_1/Relu"
op_type: "Relu"
, input: "model/dense_1/Relu:0"
input: "model/dense_2/MatMul/ReadVariableOp:0"
output: "dense_2"
name: "model/dense_2/MatMul"
op_type: "MatMul"
]
```

Comment: How can you say for sure that the dropout layer is not available in the converted model? Have you forgotten to add the output of the test.graph.node?

Comment: I am not used to look at onnx models so I might be wrong. The only thing I checked is to print the test.graph.node as shown in my question. And there, no mention of Dropout appears. Yes sorry adding the output could have probably helped, I just edited my question accordingly.